# Can Glass applications be paused?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

On a regular Android device, an application is paused when it loses focus but retains visibility. On the Glass, it looks like only one application can be visible at a time and there's no way to change focus.

So it looks like there's no pause state for Glass applications. Is this correct?

Comment: `protected void onPause()` should be available

Comment: That's true, but is there anything the user can do to trigger the paused state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should find onPause for an Activity will be called in these (and possibly more) situations:

- when the Activity is put into the background due to a new Activity replacing it on the stack,
- when the device sleeps (due to timeout or head nod),
- when user navigates back out of the app but system keeps it in memory.